# Why is my cell based NSTableView calling viewForTableColumn?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I have a view controller that's the delegate for 2 tables, a view based table and a cell based table. The cell based table is calling `viewForTableColumn` when it should be calling `objectValueForTableColumn`. I made doubly sure it was a cell based table in the interface builder.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'd like NSViewController instance to be a delegate for both view based and cell based tables. Unfortunately, while tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: method is called for cell based one, its content is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 5):

If the delegate of the `NSTableView` implements the method `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, the `NSTableView` automatically switches to view based.
You'll have to make different delegates for the 2 table views

Answer (score 1):

View-Based Table Views and Cell-Based Table Views do not mix, you can either have two different delegates or you can turn the cell bases table to a view based table and then use the following code in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` to make it look like a cell-based table:

`NSTableCellView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"textFieldCell" owner:self];`

where `textFieldCell` is the identifier of the cell. Then you set the string you want to appear in the cell using this code:

`[[cell textField] setStringValue:desiredString];`

at the end of the method return the variable cell

Comment: Where & how do you set @"textFieldCell" to be the identifier? (programmatically)